# Google Analytics Tracker Code (GATC) [a Javascript] needs to be modified to enable it to run in JSF

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, google-analytics

In a few days, I have a small event in which I have to demonstrate the Google Analytic thoroughly **only in JSF**. I have registered myself on the Google Analytics site [here](http://www.google.com/analytics/) and performed the rest of the necessary steps. I obtained the following code in Javascript on that site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." :
    "http://www.");

    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-   
    analytics.com/ga.js'    type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   try{
          var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxx-x");
          pageTracker._trackPageview();
      } 
   catch(err) {}
</script>
```

---

It is called **Google Analytics Tracker Code (GATC)** which when included on pages of a web site, the relevant information regarding the page can be view as a report. It can be used to track all the usual site activities, such as  visits, page views, page per visits, bounce rate, average time on the site etc. This is much about GATC. I have to demonstrate it only in JSF and therefore, some necessary changes must be done in order to make the above Javascript code run in JSF, since JSF uses some different way to compile Javascript. Which necessary changes need to be made in the above Javascript code so that it can run in JSF also, can I find a website on the internet which uses Google Analytic? (so that I need not upload my JSF application for demonstration which I have already developed in JSF) and If such a website(s) exists, can it be used just for demonstration? On which event of Javascript, this code should be placed? I found some relevant questions on Google Analytic already posted here but they were not especially related to JSF.

Comment: No, JSF does not use "some different way to compile JavaScript."  By the time your JSF pages make it to the client browser, it's all HTML, and the browser and its JavaScript interpreter don't know and don't care anything at all about JSF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I have to demonstrate it only in JSF and therefore, some necessary changes must be done in order to make the above Javascript code run in JSF, since JSF uses some different way to compile Javascript*

This makes no sense. JSF doesn't use a different way to "compile" JavaScript. Just put that JavaScript code there where Google Analytics [told](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html) you to put it. Here's a citation of relevance (emphasis mine):

> #### [Use the Tracking Snippet to Track Your Website](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html)
>
> The Analytics snippet is a small piece of JavaScript code that you paste into your pages. It activates Google Analytics tracking by inserting `ga.js` into the page. To use this on your pages, copy the code snippet below, replacing `UA-XXXXX-X` with your web property ID. **Paste this snippet into your website template page so that it appears before the closing `</head>` tag.**
>
> If you need to do more than basic page tracking, see the [tracking reference](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApi.html) for a list of methods available in the API and see the [Usage Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html) for details on using the asynchronous syntax. For step-by-step instructions on setting up tracking, see the Help Center article on [setting up tracking](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174090).
>
> ```html
> <script type="text/javascript">
>
>   var _gaq = _gaq || [];
>   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
>   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
>
>   (function() {
>     var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
>     ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
>     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
>   })();
>
> </script>
> ```
>
> The snippet above represents the minimum configuration needed to track a page asynchronously. It uses `_setAccount` to set the page's web property ID and then calls `_trackPageview` to send the tracking data back to the Google Analytics servers.

That code doesn't contain any XML-special characters, so nothing needs to be escaped when used on Facelets.

Comment: That code doesn't contain any XML-special characters, so nothing needs to be escaped when used on Facelets. This is something special and being not covered in the whole scenario above.

Comment: This is what every web developer needs to know about JavaScript and XML/XHTML. This is not JSF specific. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_JavaScript_for_XHTML JSF doesn't "compile" JavaScript at all. Facelets is a XML based view technology and parses the views into a JSF component tree using a XML (SAX) parser. This is not compiling.